# Vbs code not working in hta

Tags: html, windows, windows-7, vbscript, hta

I have this vbscript code here:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Sub Write
Set oFile = fso.OpenTextFile("Text.txt",8,true)
oFile.close
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "m1.hta"
End Sub
```

This will make a text file and launch m1.hta and it works perfectly. However when i put it in to a hta file like this:

```
<Script Language="VBscript">
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Sub Write
Set oFile = fso.OpenTextFile("Text.txt",8,true)
oFile.close
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "m1.hta"
End Sub
</Script>
<input type="Button" value="GO" onclick="Write">
```

I seem to be getting this error:

[image: Image of error]

My question is first what is wrong with the code and secondly how would I fix it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")` with this `CreateObject("WScript.Shell")`

Answer (score 0):

**HTA file** uses `mshta.exe` to run the script. `mshta.exe` can't recognize `wscript` object.This is reason for that error.

When running `.vbs` file, `wscript.exe` will be used which will run your code perfectly.

So removing `wscript` form your code should work fine.